# Pass pluginname within function parameters [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to pass plugin name within params?

I did as below but it isn't correct because here the plugin name is passed as a string and I cannot fire it directly. Any help please?

```
function doSomething(pluginName, elements, prop) {
    elements.forEach(function(elt) {
        if( pluginName && $(elt).length > 0 ) {
            $(elt).pluginName( prop );
        } else {
            console.log( 'Plugin is not yet loaded' );
        }
    });
}    
doSomething( 'autocomplete', '.cities', {});
```

Comment: please format properly your code and add missing parens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bracket notation when accessing methods of a jQuery object. As such, you can provide a string to it, like this:

```
elements.forEach(function(elt) {
    if(jQuery()[pluginName] && $(elt).length > 0 ) {
        $(elt)[pluginName](prop);
    } else {
        console.log( 'Plugin is not yet loaded' );
    }
});
```

Note that `jQuery()[pluginName]` is used to check if the plugin is loaded, and `$(elt)[pluginName]()` is used to call the plugin itself.